# jsoncpp how to check if tag is null .isNull() throw assertion

Tags: c++, assertions, jsoncpp

Im using jsoncpp , its great but when i need to check if json structure contains tag
when i do it with :

```
UserRoot0["error"].isNull()
```

its throws me assert from json_value.cpp line 1025

```
JSON_ASSERT( type_ == nullValue  ||  type_ == objectValue );
```

i want to check if response im getting is from this type:

```
{
    "error" : {
        "message" : "Error validating application.",
        "type" : "OAuthException",
        "code" : 190
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `[]` operator is only valid for `JsonValue` objects that are of type `Object` or null.  All others (`Int`, `Bool`, `Array`, etc.) will assert.

If your `UserRoot0` object is an `Array` or some other non-`Object` type, you have some more work to do (like iterating into sub-nodes) to find your target node that may or may not contain the error.  Print `UserRoot0.toStyledString()` to see what your JSON looks like, and make sure it looks like a JSON Object (see [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for a nice overview of what that is).

A "ToDo" comment at the top of the json_value.cpp source file (where `JSON_ASSERT` is defined) implies that the developers may be planning more robust error handling instead of these asserts in future versions, but in the meantime, you can check yourself, like this:

```
if(UserRoot0.isObject() && UserRoot0.isMember("error"))
    // Process error node
else
    // This node isn't an Object node or doesn't contain the "error" key
```

The `isMember()` check will also assert for non-`Object` nodes, so be sure to check `isObject()` before checking `isMember()` if `UserRoot0` isn't guaranteed to be an `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this too. As Ennael says you need to make sure you are dealing with an object type. FWIW my problem was caused by using JSON like this:

```
    "error" : {
        "code" : 190
    }
```

... instead of what I intended:

```
{
    "error" : {
        "code" : 190
    }
}
```

Excluding the outer set of parenthesis will cause the value type to become string instead of object.

Comment: There is a new setting, [`failIfExtra`](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_char_reader_builder.html#ac69b7911ad64c171c51ebaf2ea26d958), which will catch this common error. It is also part of `strictMode()`.